# what does CSS3 and HTML5 have in common?

Tags: html, cross-browser, css

They are only supported in new browsers. I think everyone here knows that. But if majority of users are still on older browsers that don't support CSS3/HTML5, shouldn't that push developers to use older scripting languages (ie:HTML4/CSS2).

Comment: So html and css are scripted languages now?

Comment: absolutely not.  push the newer technologies as much as you can.  If IE6 dies as a result of not being able to keep up - that would be a "Good Thing"[TM]

Comment: So we should still be using Cobol because at one time it was what the "older hardware" supported?

Answer (score 5):

They are both draft specifications which are partially supported (to various degrees) in current browsers.

> shouldn't that push developers to use older scripting languages (ie:HTML4/CSS2).

Leaving aside neither of those being scripting languages…

Using draft features can provide a better experience in some browsers, while the fallback is still acceptable.

JavaScript can sometimes be used to support browsers which don't have native support for a feature (although usually with a performance hit for those browsers).

Building around draft features provides practical experience with how those features work (and helps determine if there needs to be more work on the design before the feature goes into a final specification).

Building JS based around draft features gives common ground for different developers to aim for when building scripts to achieve a specific task. This increases the interoperability and ability to switch third party scripts.

Answer (score 3):

**No**, we as developers need to push forward.  Tools like [Google Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) and [Explorer Canvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) will allow us to push the edge without too much worry about the [browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6) that [can't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_7) [keep up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8).

Comment: With regard to Frame: you're still dependent on whether the client installs that or not. Besides, I find it nonsensicial. Why would you improve an ancient browser instead of just installing a brand new browser? Then rather do something like as http://ie6nomore.com.

Comment: BalusC, Because, ironically, some organizations allow employees to install IE plugins as opposed to switch to another browser.  In principal, I agree with you though.

Answer (score 2):

As @Rob states most of HTML5 is just HTML4 with defined error handling. Assuming you are not using the new parts of HTML5, there are no disadvantages and several benefits to using the HTML5 doctype now, including a better spec and a better validator.

A lot of CSS3 (rounded corners, drop shadows, RGBa, @font-face…) can be used as progressive enhancement on top of CSS2.1 rules. Conveniently this is also the CSS3 that is most implemented.

I think this question points to either a misunderstanding of HTML5 & CSS3, or a misunderstanding of underpinning concepts like progressive enhancement, the web trifle/layer cake, and the cascade.

For further explanation, please refer to: [Do websites need to look exactly the same in every browser](http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[What HTML5 can you reasonably expect to be able to use reliably cross-browser in the early months of 2010?](http://24ways.org/2009/html5-tool-of-satan-or-yule-of-santa)

As the article above states, there is [ExplorerCanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) until IE supports the `<canvas/>` tag.

There is also [svgweb](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/) until IE supports SVG.

And [Microsoft announced CSS3 support in IE9](http://www.css3.info/microsoft-announces-css3-support-for-internet-explorer-9-ie9/). As IE is pushed through Windows Update, I'm not afraid of using CSS3 and HTML5 right now.

Comment: IE has never given any indication of supporting canvas. I've heard of problems with svgweb on IE but don't recall what they were (slow?). While IE9 may "add" some CSS3 support, it doesn't mean it will approach all the other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

> shouldn't that push developers to use
>   older scripting languages
>   (ie:HTML4/CSS2)?

If that's your only question, then your answer is yes. "Most" developers are still using HTML 4.01 and mostly CSS2 for the reasons you stated: they're well supported on today's popular browsers. :D

See these:

[should I switch to html5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186264/is-it-time-to-start-using-html5)

[support of CSS3 among common browsers](http://www.webdevout.net/browser-support#css) (not very good yet..)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, use the broadly supported options now but make sure that your designs degrade 'gracefully' with browsers that don't support these new features as they will just ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 is mostly backwards compatible with HTML4.01, and the same browsers will still be able to handle HTML4.01 elements. Like all properties in CSS, developers will be aware and careful of how the CSS3 properties they use will affect users who can't see them (typically IE users).